# Angular search stops on single string array

Tags: angularjs, full-text-search

Using angular 10.

I am populating a table rows through a string array. Contents of the table can be searched using search box. However when I enter more than 1 character it shows no data in table while there are enterires in string array that contains the text as entered in search box

```
mysearch.ts
----------
searchText:string;
months:string[]= ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep']
----------
mySearch.html
----------
<form class="suggest-srch">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchText"  type="text" autocomplete="off" name="searchText"><button><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</form>

<table class="table">
      
        <tbody>
            
            <tr *ngFor="let data of months | filter:searchText;; let i = index">
                <td>{{data}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
----------
```

Enter text : ar
Expected output 'Mar', 'Apr'
Actual Output: blank

Enter text:  ju
Expected output 'Jun', 'Jul'
Actual Output: blank

What am I missing

Comment: Can also include your filter custom pipe file

Comment: No custom pipe file as using default filter of angular.

Comment: I think you're confusing angularJS with angular. Your post is tagged angularJS but the code you're showing is angular. AngularJS di dhave built in filter pipes, but not angular. With angular you need to create your own. Here's a tutorial that matches what you're doing: https://coderjony.com/blogs/creating-a-pipe-to-filter-the-items-in-the-list-using-angular-7/